# Highlight cell when dropdown selection matches one in list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel sheet I'm working on and I need to highlight a cell (with a dropdown) when it matches a text value in a list of specified text values. I understand conditional formatting but no matter what I try I can't make it work.

**Example of what I'm trying to do**:

In cells A14 through A23, users are going to select from a dropdown that I've already set up. For example's sake, let's say they're the fifty states.

I would like to highlight the cell after they make their selection **if** they selected a state I've put in a defined list of those I'd like to highlight.

I can't use VBS for a number of reasons. I'm using Excel '07.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ColumnC happens to be the validation list and `D14:D18` the Sates to be highlighted. In `A14` Format values where this formula is true:

> =A14=VLOOKUP(A14,D$14:D$18,1,FALSE)

and Applies to `=$A$14:$A$23`:

[image: SO17959519 example]